# Grails console plugin (unexpected results)

Tags: grails

I have the two domain clases:

```
class Persona {

    String nombre
    String apellidos

    static hasMany = [pertenencias: Pertenencia]

    static constraints = {

    }

    static mapping = {
        pertenencias cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
    }
}


class Pertenencia {

    String nombre
    static belongsTo = [persona:Persona]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

The service:

```
class MembresiaService {

@Transactional
    def saveAll() {
        def p = new Persona(nombre: 'carlos', apellidos: 'gm')
        p.addToPertenencias(nombre: 'auto')
        p.addToPertenencias(nombre: 'computadora')
        p.addToPertenencias(nombre: 'casa')
        p.save()
    }

    @Transactional
    def deletePertenencias() {
        def p = Persona.get(1)
        p.pertenencias?.clear()
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
class TestController {
    def membresiaService

    def index() {}

    def saveAll() {
        membresiaService.saveAll()
        redirect(action: "index")
    }

    def deletePertenencias() {
        membresiaService.deletePertenencias()
        redirect(action: "index")
    }
}
```

When I execute `saveAll()` method from controller it saves the data in the database, when I execute `deletePertenencias()` from controller it deletes the "pertenecias" collection of Persona from the database (as expected).

I have installed the [Grails console plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/console) , first time I execute the lines of `saveAll()` service method in the console, the result is the "persona" and its "pertenencias" in database. Then I execute the lines of `deletePertenencias()` service method in console but it doesn't delete the data of database and the "persona" object mantains the "pertenencias" (as if I had not run deletePertenencias() code).

Anyone kwnow why the code executed from console gives unexpected results? 
I expect the result was the same from controller and console but the behaviour is different.

Comment: In the service, `saveAll()` creates new `Persona` and `Pertenencia` instances.  And `deletePertenencias()` always clears the `pertenencias` collection but only for the `Persona` instance with ID 1. Is this the way the real code works, or is it a mistake in the example?

Comment: This is for simplicity, I restart grails for test from id 1